# Get key/value pairs of children

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to populate a map with key/value pairs of the data from my firebase database. Here's my database structure:

[image: database structure]

The highest level fields under `recipes/` are the uID's, and the fields within those are the individual recipe ids. When I was retrieving just the current logged in users data, this was fine, as I was only reading one level deep, and was able to get proper key/value pairs out.

I'm trying to retrieve all of the recipes. It would be easiest if I could have a map populated with just the key/value of the individual recipe ids and their values, disregarding the uid field here, but anything that's properly stored in a map would work. But the problem I've run in to is that I can't seem to find a way to dynamically query through the uids as the only known id is the current logged in user. Here's what I've got so far:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('recipes/');
ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        var key = childSnapshot.key;
        allRecipesMap.set(key, childData);
    });
});
```

With this code, I can get a map with two key/value pairs, and the value for these is all of the children of the user. What I'd really like is to also get the key/value pairs of each of the recipes individually, not just a key of the user with the recipes being the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I'd really like is to also get the key/value pairs of each of the recipes individually, not just a key of the user with the recipes being the values

To be able to do that, then you can do the following:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('recipes/');
ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        childSnapshot.forEach(function(subChildSnapshot) {
        var childData = subChildSnapshot.val();
        var key = subChildSnapshot.key;
      });
    });
});
```

Adding another `forEach` will give you all the details for the recipe and its id also.

Comment: I know I'm not technically supposed to do this, but thanks a ton, worked like a charm!